# Maven : Download of executable zip based on OS

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, operating-system

I want to download a zip file via mavens POM.XML, but based on the OS i need different URLs (Linux/Windows).

How can I change the URL based on the OS maven is executed? (locally, its Windows, on Jenkins its then Linux)

**This is how the plugins part of my POM.XML looks like**:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- the wget goal actually binds itself to this phase by default -->
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wget</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>https://test/chromedriver_win32.zip</url>
                        <unpack>true</unpack>
                        <outputFileName>chromedriver</outputFileName>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/chromeDriver</outputDirectory>-->
                        <outputDirectory>${user.home}/localdata/tools/chromeDriver</outputDirectory>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <skipCache>true</skipCache>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You can just use an environment variable

Comment: @PaulSamsotha how? can you provide an example ?

Comment: You can used profiles with activation based on the OS.